# Sort value in txt file contain {string, number} using Python

Tags: python, sorting, txt

I have a .txt file as per below:

```
testa, 10
testb, 50
testc, 20
```

I want to sort it reversely, based on the number each line located on the right side of comma, become the result like below:

```
testb, 50
testc, 20
testa, 10
```

I have tried to append each line to a list and use `sort()`, but fail.
Any way to do that in Python? Take note my file is txt.

Comment: The "csv" module may help.

Answer (score 1):

This prints the lines in reverse order

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
 
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x.split()[1], reverse=True):
        f.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Edited to write the `out.txt` file

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `key=func` argument to the `sorted()` built-in function, which specify a value to be used as comparing value between items. The code to do it would be:

```py
lines = open('input.txt').read().splitlines()
splitted = (line.split(', ') for line in lines)
items = ((i[0], int(i[1])) for i in splitted)

# Reversed sort
reversed_items = sorted(items, key=lambda i: -i[1])

open('output.txt', 'w+').write('\n'.join((f"{i[0]}, {i[1]}" for i in reversed_items)))
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Comment: Hi I have the error message like below:
```
items = ((i[0], int(i[1])) for i in splitted)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My txt file is like this:
```
testa,180
testb,200
```
Thanks

Comment: Try changing `splitted = (line.split(', ') for line in lines)` to `splitted = (line.split(',') for line in lines)`. The code above is done according to your data provided in the question though (with a space after the comma)

Comment: Oops it's my bad hahah, thanks it work now